# Is there app script to stop someone leaving a page before all data is complete?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with a list of staff who are to receive email alerts. There are 4 branches in column B and 4 responsibilities in Column C and there must be an email recorded against all 16 responsibilities. I want an app script to force a user to enter an email address against each responsibility for each branch before they can leave the page. I have an 'Exit Page' button which currently has an app script to take the user to the home page but the user could also leave the page by exiting out or by choosing another sheet. Below is a sample of my data:

[image: Email Alerts]
[image: Return Home Script]

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Can't be done. The user has full control over their operating system and web browser, and Google will **never** expose controls in Apps Script that can control the user's operating system (e.g. to prevent the browser from navigating to a URL). You need to rethink what you are asking of your users.

Comment: What about an error message before exit?

Comment: @tehhowch - what about an error message before exit?

Comment: No, Apps Script cannot even know that a page navigation is about to happen in the Sheets UI. Editors can generally unhide and reorder sheets too.

Comment: The most you could do is to show a warning when opening or editing the document, using a trigger(https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) and a browser function (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser).

Answer (score 0):

You can hide all other sheets, which will force the user to click "Exit Page".

In the exit page script you can check for empty email in a loop and force him to enter it

```
var emails = sheet1.getRange("E6:E21").getValues();

for (i=0; i<16; i++) {
   if (emails[i][0]==""){
   sheet1.getRange("E"+(i+6)).activate();
   Browser.messagebox("Pl. fed the missing email ID. Can't be left blank");
   return;
   }
}
```

It will allow him to exit only if all emails are filled.

Comment: Isn't this a warning that there is a field that is not filled. How does it stop the user from exiting?

Comment: It is not only a warning, it will stop him from leaving the sheet. If all the emails are filled, only then, it will allow him to hide the active sheet t and activate home sheet

Comment: Yes, I see; I was only thinking that there was little to stop a user from clicking the big red "X" and to close the sheet.